# What is the correct way to structure a module directory so that the Sphinx extension autodoc can access all files found using sphinx-apidoc?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying to make documentation using Sphinx for a module which I've recently started creating. How do I organise my code so that both autodoc and python can read it properly?

I have the following file structure in which `inference.py` imports a `Class` from `create_data.py`:

```
[meg_analysis]
  |
  |-[docs]
  |    |
  |    |-{files created by apidoc}
  |
  |-create_data.py
  |-inference.py
```

`sphinx-apidoc` creates a file called `meg_analysis.rst` which contains ReST directives including:

```
.. automodule:: meg_analysis.inference
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

When I run `make html`, I get this message:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'inference' from module 'meg_analysis'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'create_data'
```

I can fix this error by changing the import statement from `from create_data import SimulatedData` to `from meg_analysis.create_data import SimulatedData`.

The issue is then that now when I run `python inference.py` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'meg_analysis'` and PyCharm starts underlining all of its uses in red.

Is there a way that I can get `autodoc` to successfully document all of my files without having to include a module-level import every time I want to use something from another part of the module? Am I structuring my code wrongly in some fundamental way?

Comment: Is `meg_analysis` supposed to be a package and `inference` a submodule of that package? Then there should be a `__init__.py` file in the `meg_analysis` directory. `automodule:: meg_analysis.inference` means "document the inference module in the meg_analysis package".

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I do actually have a `__init__.py` in `meg_analysis` but it's empty. Should I have populated it with something?

Comment: You don't have to populate `__init__.py`. It can be empty.

Comment: These kinds of issues can be a bit difficult to diagnose without a [mcve]. Does `sys.path` (set via PYTHONPATH in PyCharm?) contain an entry that points to the directory above `meg_analysis`? If not, the "No module named 'meg_analysis'" error is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding both the project directory and the directory above fixed the issue.

In the `conf.py` file created by `sphinx-quickstart`, add the lines

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/{USER_NAME}/PycharmProjects/')
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/{USER_NAME}/PycharmProjects/meg_analysis/')
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it seems to work.